# Email Sending Failure using Sendgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, sendgrid

I am facing this issue last 2 days.Email Trigger is working using SpecifiedPickupDirectory.But if when I want implement real time it gives following error as mention below.
This is the error Email failure .
"Failure sending mail." with an inner IOException "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed".

This is my code please check

```
          MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("smruti.m@xx.com", 

            // From
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("info@xx.com", "XXX");

            // Subject and multipart/alternative Body
            mailMsg.Subject = "SendGrid: Testing";
            string text = "Text Body";
            string html = @"<p>Testing HTML Body</p><p><li data-tb-region-item=""><a href=>AT&amp;T Profit Beats Expectations Despite Losing Television Subscribers </a></li></p>";
            mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

            // Init SmtpClient and send
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Userid", "Password");
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```